# Anchors with Markdown in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, markdown

I have trouble making an anchor in Markdown/Visual Studio.

I made something like this:

```
### Newstuff
 * [**Meetings:**](#meetings) blabla
```

and from there i wanna link down to the Meetings header (on the same page)

```
### <a id="meetings"></a>Meetings
```

i also tried:

```
### <a name="meetings"></a>Meetings
```

and all kind of variations with closing the tag n stuff. 
Standard HTML linking doesn't work either.
Hopefully someone can point me to the right direction I tried everything i found about that topic.

I already had it working once but ... surprise didn't saved it..

Comment: That looks correct to me. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Could you post the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The problem was in the URL - i had to write:

```
[Meetings](/#/about#meetings)
```

Thank you all!